# Steam streaming changes my default communication device

Tags: steam, pc, windows, audio-hardware, steam-in-home-streaming

I have a Windows 11 PC with speakers as the default audio device and headphones as the [default communication device](https://superuser.com/q/140978/358766). I sometimes use Steam stream games to other devices. Whenever I finish streaming my audio settings get messed up where my speakers will be set as the default for both audio and communication.

I suspect the issue relates to how Steam temporarily changes audio devices to "Steam Streaming Speakers" when streaming. Steam is likely resetting my default audio device when the stream ends, but it forgets to reset my communication device. (Although I don't encounter this issue with SteamVR, despite it also temporarily overriding my audio device settings.)

How do I get Steam to stop changing my default communication device when I stream games to another device?

[image]

Comment: Windows is often annoying when it comes to it determining which outputs/inputs to use. I usually flat out disable any device I don't use. For example, my monitors have speakers, but I only ever use my headset, so I disable the monitors completely in that dialog.  Once disabled, Windows can't use it anymore, thus it has no choice but to use the only available device.

Comment: @TimmyJim In this case I have 2 audio devices actively being used, so disabling either one of them wouldn't work.